# When and where to encode user input?

Tags: forms, encoding, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I am currently storing data submitted from users into my database already encoded like such:

```
<cfquery>
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (UserID, Comment)
VALUES
(
<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.UserID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"/>,
<cfqueryparam value="#EncodeForHTML(FORM.Comment)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar"/>
)
</cfquery>
```

Evidently this is not the right way to do it because now I have escaped characters in my DB table which are only useful for HTML output and difficult to perform searches on within SQL Server.

So how do I ensure that I apply the `EncodeForHTML()` on the input before it hits the server and then `Canonicalize()` the data received to be stored in the DB?

Answer (score 4):

Mitigate potentially DB-harmful text when it heads towards the DB: pass it as a parameter, not hard-coded into the SQL statement, as you have kinda done in your example. You are still exposing yourself by not parameterising your ID value. As a rule, only SQL should go in your `<cfquery>`'s SQL string; any data values should be passed as parameters.

Similarly, mitigate risk your user-provided data might expose *when you use the data*. Not when it goes into storage, but when you actually use it. `encodeForHtml()` is only appropriate for stuff being written into HTML. It's no help if it's being passed on a URL, or used in JavaScript, etc. There are different mitigation approaches for those (`urlEncodedFormat()` and `encodeForJavaScript()` respectively). The point being you handle the mitigation on a use-by-use basis, not just generically.

And how to ensure this is done (you ask this)? Well... you write your code diligently and have a rigorous code review and QA process (with QA doing pen. tests).

Comment: When you say pass it as a parameter, do you mean I need to use Stored Procedures for everything and provide values through SQL parameters? I didn't quite understand what this meant. I am using `<cfqueryparam>` wherever possible. I guess I misunderstood the CF documentation on preventing XSS attacks. I had it in my head that all user inputs must be encoded.

Comment: I meant using bound parameters, as you are doing with `<cfqueryparam>` in your code example. At the time I offered my answer, you *hadn't* parameterised the `FORM.UserID` value, which you subsequently have. To get rid of XSS you do two things: probably have an AntiSamy policy in place, and escape all user-originated output when you come to output it. Many ppl clean it on the way IN to the DB, but as you don't know how you're going to be using the data, this is not the better approach. Escape it appropriately at the time you need to escape it.

Comment: So if I've got this right: I use `EncodeForHTML()` only where I don't want the browser to execute/render the code and I use an Anti-Samy `GetSafeHTML()` to clean up user inputs which may contain HTML elements that will need to be displayed on the page. Because if I use `EncodeForHTML()` on data that needs to be shown on the page, it doesn't render properly and shows the actual HTML code on the page instead (bit like source code view)

Comment: Just try it! Isn't that better than asking someone else? `encodeForHtml()` will escape all HTML in the content, so it will not render, it'll just display. If you *need* to allow ppl to enter HTML which is then actually rendered, you need to put it through an AntiSamy filter at the time they enter it to remove anything you won't permit (and optionally tell them you've done so, etc). There is *stacks* of stuff written about this. Just google it and read it.

Comment: It was just strange having to `EncodeForHTML` in the meta tags and then not use it on the page. Its taken me a while to understand the key difference between encoding and anti-samy, and how, when and where to use each of them. I bet a lot of people don't understand it despite the stuff written about it. Seeing html encoded information not rendering on a page would make many people confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can store them as is, and use `<cfqueryparam>` for `form.userid` as well.  On output, you use `encodeforhtml()`.

If you prefer to have some data sanitizing done before storing, try AntiSamy (built-in in CF11) http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/security-improvements-cf11.edu.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2

Comment: How do I prevent against XSS attacks if I don't use EncodeForHTML first?

Comment: Once you `encodeForHTML()` on display, everything will show up as is together with the code.  Therefore you'll see the actual `<tags></tags>` showing up rather than being executed by the browser.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I was storing the data already encoded. But this has turned out to be a bad idea. I just want to encode on the server, and then Canoncalize it before storing to the DB. In the CF guide on preventing XSS attacks it says I must encode user submitted values. So now I don't understand how and when to do it.

Comment: well sometimes it doesn't matter and no rule works for everyone.  As long as you only canonicalize once, and encode once before outputting, you should be fine.